# Partial differential equation question: $UU_{x}=(U+1)U_{t}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I’m currently a year 10 in high school and I’ve recently been really interested in partial differential equations. I can only solve really simple ones though due to gaps in my knowledge. Anyway, one day while waiting for my teacher to print out a practice test I decided to come up with a simple looking PDE and try to solve it. I tried solving it but it turned out to be more complex than I expected so I was wondering if someone could help me solve it if it is solvable. Anyway, the question is

$$UU_{x}=(U+1)U_{t}.$$

I managed to reduce it to a system of ordinary differential equations but I don’t know how to solve systems of ordinary differential equations or even if that was the right way to attempt the partial differential equation.

Comment: Edited your equation for readability.  Hope I did it right. If not, let me know.  Cheers!

Comment: You'll also need some boundary/initial conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this problem is so difficult is because it is *fully nonlinear*, in the sense that the highest derivatives in the equation (both $u_{t}, u_{x}$) are nonlinear. To solve this we use [the method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Whilst it may be too advanced for you, I'm not sure of another simpler way to solve the problem. So hopefully you can follow.

You have

$$(u+1)u_{t} = uu_{x}$$

The characteristic curves are determined from the [parametrization invariant form of the Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation)

$$\frac{dt}{u+1} = \frac{dx}{- u} = \frac{du}{0}$$

From the final characteristic, we have

$$u = c_{2}, \quad \text{$c_{2}$ a constant}$$

From the first equality, substituting $u = c_{2}$ and integrating, we have

\begin{align}
dx &= - \left( \frac{c_{2}}{c_{2}+1} \right) dt \\
\implies x + \left( \frac{c_{2}}{c_{2}+1} \right) t &= x + \left( \frac{u}{u+1} \right) t \\
&= c_{1}
\end{align}

Using the functional relationship $c_{2} = f(c_{1})$, we have

\begin{align}
u &= c_{2} \\
&= f(c_{1}) \\
&= f \left(x + \left( \frac{u}{u+1} \right) t \right)
\end{align}

which you can check via differentiation satisfies the PDE.